# python sending Ctrl-C to Terminal in Mac

Tags: python, sigint, sigterm

I have managed to start a VPN with this code

```
tunnel_file = "sudo /opt/local/sbin/openvpn2 primary_config.ovpn"

VPNProcess = subprocess.Popen(tunnel_file,shell = True)
```

The trouble is that I can't stop this process
I tried -

```
VPNProcess.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

and also sending SIGTERM or SIGKILL but none of them work. Not even `VPNProcess.terminate()` works.
I can list the processes, it seems two are started, a sudo process and an openvpn2 process but if I try killing them in Terminal with kill number I get the response "operation not allowed"
Any ideas?

Comment: Try it with `shell=False`.

Comment: You can't kill the `sudo` process because it's setuid, and you can't kill the `openvpn2` process because it's running as a different user (root). You probably should create a new pseudoterminal (pty) to run `sudo` in; then you can send Ctrl-C to the pty.